# Arrow kotlin Validates zip type mismatch or can't find proper method overload

Tags: kotlin, arrow-functions

I have two methods for validation:

```
fun a(s:String): Validated<Error, SomeEnum> {
}

fun b(s:String): Validated<Error, OtherEnum> {
}
```

I want to zip those two valiation methods and do something like this:

```
a(s1).zip(b(s2) { (r1, r2) -> Pair(r1, r2) }
```

However Kotlin in zip argument list complains about type mismatch:

> Required: Semigroup<TypeVariabke(E)>
>
> Found: Validated<Error, OtherEnum>

And for passed lambda there is such error message:

> Required: Validated<TypeVariable(E), TypeVariable(B)>
>
> Found: ERROR -> TypeVariable(_L)

However when i change `Validated` to `ValidatedNel` then i have error about multiple implementation matching passed arguments. When I check the implementations which compiler can't choose between, I have those given below:

```
zip(ValidatedNel<E,B>, (A,B) -> Z)
zip(Semigroup<E>, ValidatedNel<E, B>)
```

However when I used below implementation Kotlin doesn't complain, but return ’Validated’ without list of errors.

```
a(s1).zip(nonEmptyList(), b(s2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turnus out i had to just remove parenthesis in the lambda so my zip should look like this:

```
a(s1).zip(b(s2)) { r1, r2 -> Pair(r1, r2) }
```

Comment: Yeah the transform function takes *two parameters*, so ``r1, r2``. If you write `(r1, r2)` that's one parameter (usually a `Pair` or something) being *destructured* into two local variables: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html